# Off by one error in imshow?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting a PGM image:
[image]
Here's the [data](http://pastebin.com/jzCVRMJ1) I'm using.

The problem is some of the shown pixels are wrong.  For example:

- the three grey boxes near the top of the image are of value 11 (so they should be red, not red)
- the two yellow pixels in the top row -- they are of value 8, so they should be yellow-green, not yellow

Can anybody explain the discrepancies and how to fix them?

Here's my source:

```
from pylab import *
import numpy    
LABELS = range(13)
NUM_MODES = len(LABELS)
def read_ascii_pgm(fname):
    """
    Very fragile PGM reader.  It's OK since this is only for reading files
    output by my own app.
    """
    lines = open(fname).read().strip().split('\n')
    assert lines[0] == 'P2'
    width, height = map(int, lines[1].split(' '))
    assert lines[2] == '13'
    pgm = numpy.zeros((height, width), dtype=numpy.uint8)
    for i in range(height):
        cols = lines[3+i].split(' ')
        for j in range(width):
            pgm[i,j] = int(cols[j])
    return pgm
def main():
    import sys
    assert len(sys.argv) > 1
    fname = sys.argv[1]
    pgm = read_ascii_pgm(fname)
    # EDIT: HACK!
    pgm[0,0] = 12
    cmap = cm.get_cmap('spectral', NUM_MODES)
    imshow(pgm, cmap=cmap, interpolation='nearest')
    edit = True
    if edit:
        cb = colorbar()
    else:
        ticks = [ (i*11./NUM_MODES + 6./NUM_MODES) for i in range(NUM_MODES) ]
        cb = colorbar(ticks=ticks)
        cb.ax.set_yticklabels(map(str, LABELS))
    savefig('imshow.png')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**EDIT**

I see what's happening here now.  Basically, `imshow` seems to be doing this:

- determining the dynamic range (as `[ min(image), max(image) ]`
- represent this using the number of colors specified in the color map (13 colors)

What I want it to do is:

- use the dynamic range that I specified when creating the color map (13)
- represent this using the 13 colors in the color map

I can verify this by forcing the dynamic range of the image to be 13 (see the line labelled `HACK`).  Is there a better way to do this?

Here's an updated image:
[image]

Comment: +1 - This seems to be an issue a lot of people could run into, getting "almost correct" results. Would hate to catch this _after_ publishing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to set `im.set_clim(vmin, vmax)`.  Basically the values in the image were being translated to cover the entire color range.  For example if `3` was the largest value in your data, it would be assigned the maximum color value.

Instead you need to tell it that `max_nodes` is the highest value (13 in your case), even though it doesn't appear in the data, e.g. `im.set_clim(0, 13)`.

I changed your code slightly to work with other data files with different values for `num_modes`:

```
import numpy
from pylab import *

def read_ascii_pgm(fname):
    lines = open(fname).read().strip().split('\n')
    assert lines[0] == 'P2'
    width, height = map(int, lines[1].split(' '))
    num_modes = int(lines[2])
    pgm = numpy.zeros((height, width), dtype=numpy.uint8)
    for i in range(height):
        cols = lines[3+i].split(' ')
        for j in range(width):
            pgm[i,j] = int(cols[j])
    return pgm, num_modes + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    assert len(sys.argv) > 1
    fname = sys.argv[1]
    pgm, num_modes = read_ascii_pgm(fname)
    labels = range(num_modes)
    cmap = cm.get_cmap('spectral', num_modes)
    im = imshow(pgm, cmap=cmap, interpolation='nearest')
    im.set_clim(0, num_modes)
    ticks = [(i + 0.5) for i in range(num_modes)]
    cb = colorbar(ticks=ticks)
    cb.ax.set_yticklabels(map(str, labels))
    savefig('imshow_new.png')
```

Some simpler test data to illustrate. Notice that the `num_modes` value is 10, but no data point reaches that level. This shows how the values index into the colormap 1:1:

```
P2
5 3
10
0 1 0 2 0
3 0 2 0 1
0 1 0 2 0
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I caught this right before coming back here to see your answer.  I'm actually passing the min and max as arguments to `imshow` but it's essentially the same thing. Thanks for the easy-to-understand write-up!

Answer (score 3):

There's no discrepancy, you're just manually setting the ticks to be labeled with values that aren't what they actually are.

Notice that your `LABELS` is just `range(13)`, while your actual tick locations (`ticks`) don't range from 0 to 12.

So, you're manually labeling the top tick, which has a position of 10.6, as 12!

Try taking out the line `cb.ax.set_yticklabels(map(str, LABELS))`, and you'll see what I mean (Also, matplotlib will automatically cast them to strings. There's no reason to call `map(str, LABELS)`).

Perhaps instead of using a static set of numbers as labels, you should just convert your actual tick locations to labels? Something like `[round(tick) for tick in ticks]`?

Edit: Sorry, that sounded snarkier than I intended it to...  I didn't mean it to sound that way! :)

**Edit2**: 
In response to the updated question, yes, `imshow` determines the range automatically from the min and max of the input. (I'm confused... What else would it do?)

If you want a direct color mapping with no interpolation, then use one of the discrete colormaps, not a `LinearSegmentedColormap`.  However, it's easiest to just manually set the limits on a one of matplotlib's `LinearSegmentedColormap`s (which is what `matplotlib.cm.spectral` is).

If you want to manually set the range of the color mapping used, just call `set_clim([0,12])` on the coloraxis object that `imshow` returns.

E.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

with open('temp.pgm') as infile:
    header, nrows, ncols = [infile.readline().strip() for _ in range(3)]
    data = np.loadtxt(infile).astype(np.uint8)

cmap = mpl.cm.get_cmap('spectral', 13)
cax = plt.imshow(data, cmap, interpolation='nearest')
cax.set_clim([0,13])
cbar = plt.colorbar(cax, ticks=np.arange(0.5, 13, 1.0))
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(range(13))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  First of all, I disagree with you.  I think that there **is** a discrepancy.  The color bar has 13 colors, of which grey is the highest value color, dark red the second highest, red the third, etc.  The image has a max of 13 intensities (as I specified when creating the color map), of which 12 is the highest value.  Am I wrong to assume that 12 should therefore be represented as grey, and 11 as dark red?

Comment: Don't worry about sounding snarky.  You just gave me an idea as to what the problem actually is.  Please see my updated question.  And thanks!

Comment: Woops, didn't notice @samplebias's answer, which says the exact same thing as mine.  I took too long editing! :) I'll leave the answer as is, though.

Comment: @misha - That's not how a `ScalarMappable` (what imshow returns) work in matplotlib.  If you want a discrete color palette, then set `cax.norm = mpl.colors.NoNorm(0, 12)`.  Alternately (and more easily), you can just set `cax.set_clim(...)`, as in both mine and samplebias's answers.  But just to clarify, it doesn't matter what color scheme you put in, it's how the ScalarMappable object (most easily created by `plt.imshow`) scales it that matters.  Unless you specify otherwise, matplotlib always assumes it's working with continuous data.